# What does "よーく" mean?

Tags: meaning

"今回、企業の姿勢に厳しい意見が圧倒的に多数でした。でもネット上の声を**よーく**見ていると、本当に時々ですが、おっと思う体験が載っていました。"([link](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180420/k10011411371000.html?utm_int=netnewsup_contents_list-items_002))

Comment: It's just よく with emphasis put on it.

Comment: Yeah, it's the difference between "look really hard" and "look reeeeeeaaaally hard"